# Docker getting bcrypt error when run the container with nodejs application

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I've got an error when run my containers with application. Tried all solutions what I've seen in google. Add a .dockerignore file with /node_modules. Different commands in Dockerfile such as

"RUN npm rebuild bcrypt" after RUN npm ci.

Also I've tried to install bcryptjs instead of bcrypt but it returns another error.

Here is my docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3'
services:
  api:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      - PORT=3000
      - DB_HOST=localhost
      - DB_PORT=5432
      - DB_USER=user
      - DB_PW=pass
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    links:
      - postgres:postgres
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/app
      - /usr/app/node_modules

  postgres:
    image: postgres:alpine
    restart: always
    ports:
    - 5432:5432
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=db
      - POSTGRES_USER=user
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=pass
      - POSTGRES_HOST=localhost
      - POSTGRES_PORT=5432
      - DATABASE_URL=postgres://${POSTGRES_USER}:${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}@${POSTGRES_HOST}:${POSTGRES_PORT}/${POSTGRES_DB}

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
        - 8080:8080
```

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:18-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .gyp python3 make g++ postgresql-dev

RUN npm ci

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

RUN npm run build

CMD ["node", "dist/main.js"]
```

Error is:

**Error loading shared library bcrypt/lib/binding/napi-v3/bcrypt_lib.node: Exec format error**

Appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: The docker-compose.yml is likely irrelevant, but your package.json is relevant.  Is it the `npm ci` step or the `npm run build` step that produces the error? Also, there's no telling from this example what `COPY . .` has copied into your container.

Comment: The `volumes:` block in your Compose setup is hiding pretty much everything in your image, and in particular whatever's in the image's `node_modules` tree is being replaced with content from an anonymous Docker volume.  Does deleting the `volumes:` from the `api` container make any difference?

Comment: I tried to delete `volumes:` section with unchanged Dockefile but it also show the same error.

Comment: I think `COPY . .` should copy all my local files to workdir of docker container. I've checked where am I located after all commands in a docker container and checked files which are located in /usr/app folder. It's pretty much the same as on my local machine.